# Approved edits workflow problem

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

In the "review edits" page, sometimes I come across a suggested edit which is fine, except for maybe a couple of finishing touches that need to be applied.  I approve the edit, but then the link to the question completely disappears, and I'm not able to get back to the post again, unless I remembered the title so I can search for it.

Before you say it, yes I could open a separate window with the linked page in it (if I remember), but at the moment I'm working from an IPad, and that's not the easiest thing to do on an iPad.

So it would be nice if the *link only* stayed on the screen, so I could click on it and get to the edited question, if I wanted to.

Comment: 10k users can also check the [recent edits list](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/recent-edits), and mods can check the [suggested edits dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/admin/suggested-edits). But definitely that would make things a lot easier

Comment: For non-moderators there is the additional problem that half of the time you can't do those finishing touches anyway, because instead you have to wait until the post is approved by a second person.

Comment: solution: get a Macbook air, or another real computer :)

Comment: I have been bitten by this multiple times. We are looking at a way of improving this, I dislike that stuff just vanishes and you have no undo button.

Answer (score 2):

Done,

We now always float a link up to the top of the page containing  suggested edit and post